# Use SQL Server as Web Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Would it be possible to set up a SQL server as follows?

1. User enters a special URL in the browser
2. URL connects to a SQL server and calls a Stored Procedure (or Function)
3. Stored Procedure delivers HTML text as a result

No pictures are needed. Everything we need could be embedded in one single HTML.

**EDIT:**

**The core idea of this question is to go without a separate web server.** However, I don't want to re-create a full-blown web server with SQL server. My main idea is only that users could pull a HTML report directly from SQL server, without the need to take all the hassle and install a dedicated web server for this.

So technically, the core of my question is if there exists a special kind of URL which could call a stored procedure directly? Or if you can setup the SQL server in a way that it listens to some special URL calls?

**EDIT 2:**

Possibly, if SQL server could internally host a kind of "mini web server", that could also help.

Comment: Yes this is possible. The "special" url is whatever URL you specify from a web application. The code behind on that page will execute the stored proc and deliver the results to the client.

Comment: How are you planning to call a SP from the url? www.url.com?SP=sp_execute+123+abc?

Comment: @SeanLange I think he's looking for a solution that doesn't require a web application or a web server.   See his step 2.

Comment: In my opinion you this is a case of you probably can make it work, but should not want to make it work. Using tools for things that they were not ment for is hardly ever a good choice.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server?  Look here [SQL Server Reporting Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms159106.aspx) and here [wiki SQL Server Reporting Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services)

Comment: @TabAlleman yes, exactly, this is the core of my question. I'd like to know if it's possible without a dedicated web server.

Comment: @tom yes of course I know,and I'm not planning to use a SQL server as a web server. But for some scenarios it would be great if users could pull a HTML report directly from SQL server without the need to install a web server.

Comment: At all, thank you for your comments. Inded, Iwant to go without a dedicated IIS web server . I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Look into SSRS.   It does not require a web-server, and does not require any aspx pages.   However, it wouldn't work exactly how you describe, where you put HTML in the database and it would render it exactly like a web page.   Look into it and see how it does work; it might be your best option.

Answer (score 8):

Generally it is not possible without web server.

While you can output some html from stored procedure - SQL server itself lacks ability to listen for http requests and produce http responses.

In fact, dealing with http requests/responses is what web server intended to do - so there is no any reason for sql server to handle this.

Comment: Mainly, my idea is that users could pull a HTML report directly from an SQL server without the need to install a web server. Therefore, my question is if there exists a special kind of URL which coukd call a stored procedure directly.

Comment: @Giosco, well you can try to use SQL Server Reporting Services, as it was suggested by Giorgi Nakeuri. It is one of SQL Server components and it has own builtin webserver. But keep in mind - SSRS has a very limited support of html tags you can use with it.

Comment: @Giosco Alternatively - you can create some tiny application and register it as a handler for some URI schema, say "your_UI_Type://resourse?parameters". In this case when you click on such a link, it will be handled by Windows, request will be passed to this application - and then in this application you can connect to SQL Server in usual way, request data and somehow display it to user or do whatever you need. But in this case such an application has to be registered as URI handler on all clients computers for this approach to work.

Comment: Thanks, that's also a very interesting approach !

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server 2005 something like this was possible through special web endpoints. This was horribly insecure and the feature was deprecated in the later versions of SQL Server.

For current versions of SQL Server you will need some web server and some sort of middleware (asp/asp.net/php/node.js) which will make the connection on behalf of the client. As an alternative you can use SSRS (reporting service) which uses IIS as a web server to run your site.

Comment: fyi, Since 2008R2 I believe that SSRS uses its own self web host rather than IIS :)

Comment: @NeilP Aha, but that's interesting. A "self web host" is possibly something in the direction I'm looking for.

Comment: @Giosco out of interest, what is the benefit to you of using a self hosted application over using  IIS?

Comment: @NeilP My customers only maintain a SQL server, they have no IIS.

Answer (score 2):

With `SSRS`:

> 1. User enters a special URL in the browser

Enters something like http://127.0.0.1/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fsome%2fname`

> 2. URL connects to a SQL server and calls a Stored Procedure (or Function)

Report connects to database and gets result.

> 3. Stored Procedure delivers HTML text as a result

Stored procedure returns plain result set. But you can generate report in `MHTML` format.